# Best way to do sync separation without an LM1881 or equivalent

Tags: pic, video

I have a PAL or NTSC video signal and I want to extract the CSYNC information. Preferably, I would like to avoid using an LM1881, because I am short on space and I'm optimising for cost.  Also, the LM1881 is limited to an operating range of 0°C to +70°C and I want a full industrial range of -40°C to +85°C.

So I set up a little divider network like this:

```
3.3V --------------+
                   |
                   /
                   \ 4.7k
                   /
       4.7u   1k   |
Inp  --| |--/\/\/\-+--- to PIC comparator
                   |
                   /
                   \ 4.7k
                   /
              1k   | 
                  ---
                   -
```

This produces a signal with ranging from 1.27V to 1.5V, but the signal moves up and down when the brightness in the scene changes! I think this is happening because the DC offset is changing.

Any idea on how to eliminate this offset? I guess I could add some other components, but I'd rather not - I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: Hmm, I may have solved my problem. Adding an 82 ohm termination resistor (close enough to 75 ohms) has significantly reduced the change from bright to dark.

Comment: Interesting. Please let us know if this actually did it for you, I am very interested in your findings.

Comment: Well, it has made the change from bright to dark less than 200mV and this can be triggered on with the scope so I'm hopeful that the signal can be compared using a PIC comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have AD sampling with PIC, then you might consider software only detection of CSYNC.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, my application needs to do some other stuff in the background, and can't be sampling the ADC continously.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with varying DC offset based on light level. I got around this by making the PIC code track the level and so the reference for the comparator would always be within the signal deflection range. It works well but now have another problem. I am trying to detect the vertical sync so I know when to switch a video multiplexer and stop any flicker or rolling. I can detect the vertical sync but cannot currently discriminate between even and odd fields. I am still getting a flicker as the two camera feeds and not genlocked. Does anyone know at what point I should switch the multiplexer, do I do it at the start of the odd field only? Or could the problem be due to the camera seeing different light levels and as they change the DC blocking cap need to charge/discharge to a different level?

Thanks,
Jose

Comment: You should post this as another question and link to this. Thanks for the answer and idea; I was thinking of doing something like this, but I didn't think that the internal reference had enough granularity. You can determine the difference between even and odd fields by the different patterns at the beginning of the field. If you have a scope with tv trigger (most good ones do), I recommend you probe it using the tv trigger, and you'll see what I mean.